# Linux command find -print. When to I need this option?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, find

What is the difference between:
`find . -name "*.txt"`  and `find . -name "*.txt" -print` ?

I mean what is the use of `print` in `find`. I see that it prints the results anyway so why is this option available?

Answer (score 2):

In very old versions of find, -print wasn't implicit so was required.

Nowadays, it is the default action but is still useful when combined with -prune to avoid the default action to encompass the pruning. eg:

This won't print files named foo under /tmp:

```
find /tmp -name foo -prune -o -type f -print
```

This will:

```
find /tmp -name foo -prune -o -type f
```

Comment: In the following nothing is printed `find . -type f \( -name ".vim" -prune \)  -print`. Why?